# Calculate return for interest-only plan as a function of reinvestment period

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

Given an investment plan which for any deposit ($D$) returns a daily rate ($r$) for the duration of 365 days, and which allows reinvestment of earnings (which are treated identically as the initial investment), I would like to calculate the total returns as a function of a period length for which the capital is initially reinvested ($p$).

I am not trying to optimize investment here, as (even though I do not have the exact function) it seems fairly obvious to me that the returns as a function of reinvestment period will be strictly increasing.

My work so far:

$p=0$:
$$S = r\cdot D \cdot 365$$

$p=1$:
$$S = r\cdot D\cdot (365-1)+\\
r\cdot r\cdot D\cdot 365
$$

$p=2$:
$$S = r\cdot D\cdot (365-2)+\\
r\cdot r\cdot D\cdot (365-1)+\\
r\cdot r\cdot (D+r\cdot D) \cdot 365
$$

$p=3$:
$$S = r\cdot D\cdot (365-3)+\\
r\cdot r\cdot D\cdot (365-2)+\\
r\cdot r\cdot (D+r\cdot D) \cdot (365-1) + \\
r\cdot r\cdot (D+r\cdot D + r\cdot(D+r\cdot D))\cdot 365
$$

I am writing everything out in the hope of better seeing some pattern. I notice the obviious increment in terms, each multiplied by decreasing integer values starting at $p$. I also notice that the previous term is somehow nested in the next term, but I really can't put any of this pattern detection in mathematical terms - and if I had to continue the series I don't notice any cognitive short cuts I would be taking. Anyway, perhaps this is more obvious if I contract the sums:

$p=0$:
$$S = 365rD$$

$p=1$:
$$
S = 365rD - rD +\\
365r^2D
$$

$p=2$:
$$
S = 365rD - 2rD +\\
2\cdot 365r^2D - r^2D +\\
365r^3D
$$

$p=3$:
$$
S = 365rD - 3rD +\\
3\cdot 365r^2D - 3r^2D +\\
3\cdot 365r^3D - r^3D +\\
360r^4D
$$

This is perhaps somewhat better. I notice that the powers of $r$ go allt he way up to $p+1$, and the highest power is always just multiplied by $360D$. All the other power terms are expressed as $x\cdot 635r^?D - x\cdot 365r^?D$ where $x=p$ - except for the lowest power, where the positive part of the term is not multiplied by $p$ and the second-highest power, where the negative part is not.

This is already shaping up to be a mouthfull, and contains a few conditional statements. I really have no idea of how to put this in mathematical terms - I only get the feeling that this would be best conceptualized as a sum of sums. But I'm seriously lost at this point. Can you help me wrap this up in a nicer form?

Comment: I didn't go through all, but your expressions look like binomial terms. So your expressions look like this : $(365-1)D(r+1)^p-D(365-1)+365Dr^{p+1}$ which may be simplified a bit more...

Comment: It would make more sense to include the return of capital and "reinvested capital" at the last period, and then subtract the original investment $D$, otherwise the concept of return is lost. To simplify calculations, you could take $D=1$ as the initial investment, WLOG.